# Trying to make a switch in Jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, switch-statement, case, keycode

I'm trying to make a switch in Jquery but it isn't really working...

This is my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    var playPause = 0;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if (keycode == '80') {
        switch (playPause) {
        case 0:
            angular.element('#playBtn').trigger('click');
                playPause = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            angular.element('#pauseBtn').trigger('click');
                playPause = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

It doesn't really work like a switch because I can only press it once and it will start, but it will never go to case 1 where it goes on pause.

**Is my switch wrong ? Please tell me how to fix this.**

This is the whole code:

```
 $(document).keydown(function (event) {
    var playPause = 0;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    event.preventDefault();

    if (keycode == '80') {
        switch (playPause) {
        case 0:
            angular.element('#playBtn').trigger('click');
                playPause = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            angular.element('#pauseBtn').trigger('click');
                playPause = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (keycode == '39') {
        angular.element('#nextBtn').trigger('click');
    }

    if (keycode == '37') {
        angular.element('#previousBtn').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: _trying to make a switch in Jquery_ i guess you are using angular.

Comment: The code that I'm using to do this is Jquery but I'm calling angular elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `playPause` variable is in local scope, not global scope, thus it always starts at 0.  Put the `var playPause = 0;` declaration before the `$(document)` line, and it should work.

Comment: I'm almost sure that `var playPause = 0;` is at the right spot to be honest.

Comment: @Goldenowner every time you `keydown` it's reset to 0

Comment: @billyonecan that's true actually, but when I place it before the $(document) it doesn't even know playPause in the switch ? and it doesn't get the right color so that's not completely right aswell..

Comment: Never mind I will shut up, you guys are right. It works now. Thank you !